# Riscv: mhartid register

Tags: assembly, riscv

I had a quick question about the csr register `mhartid` in riscv. In the doc it is said that it correspond to the hardware thread id. But does a hardware thread correspond to a physical core or it is still an abstract notion?
for exemple, can a core read different value in mhartid in the same execution sequence or a given core will always have a unique mhartid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One core can have multiple threads (what Intel calls hyper-threading).

See also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580645/what-is-a-hardware-thread-in-risc-v

The hardware thread ID will never spontaneously change during the execution of a sequence of instructions.

Comment: However, if the software thread gets rescheduled and assigned to a new hardware thread, then from the software thread's point of view, it will appear as if the hardware thread ID changed spontaneously. (Just like when you go in for surgery, you fall asleep in the operating room, but wake up in the recovery room. The room appeared to change spontaneously from your point of view, but really what happened is that you were moved from one room to another while you were asleep.)

Comment: @RaymondChen If I'm reading it correctly, `mhartid` is only available in M-mode (highest privilege), so a userland SW thread should not be able to see it was rescheduled to somewhere else by the OS. Not in this way, anyway.